# Intent android auto encode string

Tags: android, android-intent, deeplink

I am working with deep link and I got a problem when passing Japanese string from Web to Android via IntentFilter. There are some code:

Initializing webview with Html code:

```
String encode = URLEncoder.encode("namhv://category?category_name=レビュー", "UTF-8");
    Log.e(TAG, "Url Encode: " + encode);
    Log.e(TAG, "Url Decode:" + URLDecoder.decode(encode, "UTF-8"));
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_content);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    String html = "<html><body>\n" +
            "<br><a href=\"" + encode + "\">test go tab</a><br>" +
            "</body></html>";
    Log.e(TAG, html);
    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Handle Intent:

```
public boolean handleDeepLinkEvent(Intent intent) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (intent.getData() != null) { //deep link
        String cateName = intent.getDataString();
        Log.e(TAG, cateName);
        Log.e(TAG, URLDecoder.decode(cateName, "UTF-8"));
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

(1) Origin string: namhv://category?category_name=レビュー

(2) String after encoded with UTF8: namhv%3A%2F%2Fcategory%3Fcategory_name%3D%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC

(3) String received via intent: namhv://category?category_name=%C3%A3%C6%92%C2%AC%C3%A3%C6%92%E2%80%9C%C3%A3%C6%92%C2%A5%C3%A3%C6%92%C2%BC

(4) String after decoded with UTF8: namhv://category?category_name=ãƒ¬ãƒ“ãƒ¥ãƒ¼
In my expectation, (2) and (3) are same, and (1) and (4) are same. But I do not know what Android does with string when passed via IntentFilter.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved by repleace

```
 webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

by

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```